# getting problem in HashMap<String,ArrayList<Model>> , (Creating Comments View in Android )

Tags: java, android

Receiveg this Json Response

```
{
"result": "success",
"data": [
    {
        "comment": "hi",
        "addedon": "2019-03-01 09:31:28",
        "user_id": "1",
        "id": "22",
        "name": "chitransh",
        "photo": "user.png"
    },
    {
        "comment": "hixdh ",
        "addedon": "2019-03-01 09:31:32",
        "user_id": "1",
        "id": "23",
        "name": "chitransh",
        "photo": "user.png"
    },
    {
        "comment": "xy uf",
        "addedon": "2019-03-01 09:31:36",
        "user_id": "1",
        "id": "24",
        "name": "chitransh",
        "photo": "user.png"
    },
    {
        "comment": "cgui ",
        "addedon": "2019-03-01 09:31:39",
        "user_id": "1",
        "id": "25",
        "name": "chitransh",
        "photo": "user.png"
    },
    {
        "comment": "hi",
        "addedon": "2019-03-01 09:33:32",
        "user_id": "1",
        "id": "26",
        "name": "chitransh",
        "photo": "user.png"
    },
    {
        "comment": "fg ",
        "addedon": "2019-03-01 09:33:34",
        "user_id": "1",
        "id": "27",
        "name": "chitransh",
        "photo": "user.png"
    },
    {
        "comment": "chkk hhh",
        "addedon": "2019-03-01 09:33:39",
        "user_id": "1",
        "id": "28",
        "name": "chitransh",
        "photo": "user.png"
    },
    {
        "comment": "yubvcg ",
        "addedon": "2019-03-01 09:33:43",
        "user_id": "1",
        "id": "29",
        "name": "chitransh",
        "photo": "user.png"
    },
    {
        "comment": "ggi ",
        "addedon": "2019-03-01 09:33:47",
        "user_id": "1",
        "id": "30",
        "name": "chitransh",
        "photo": "user.png"
    },
    {
        "comment": "cfg hj",
        "addedon": "2019-03-01 09:33:50",
        "user_id": "1",
        "id": "31",
        "name": "chitransh",
        "photo": "user.png"
    },
    {
        "comment": "vbj",
        "addedon": "2019-03-01 09:33:53",
        "user_id": "1",
        "id": "32",
        "name": "chitransh",
        "photo": "user.png"
    },
    {
        "comment": "hehh",
        "addedon": "2019-03-01 11:32:13",
        "user_id": "18",
        "id": "33",
        "name": "Test User 3",
        "photo": "avatar10.png"
    },
    {
        "comment": "hhh",
        "addedon": "2019-03-01 11:43:26",
        "user_id": "18",
        "id": "37",
        "name": "Test User 3",
        "photo": "avatar10.png"
    },
    {
        "comment": "hahahah",
        "addedon": "2019-03-01 12:04:14",
        "user_id": "18",
        "id": "42",
        "name": "Test User 3",
        "photo": "avatar10.png"
    },
    {
        "comment": "hii",
        "addedon": "2019-03-01 12:16:05",
        "user_id": "18",
        "id": "43",
        "name": "Test User 3",
        "photo": "avatar10.png"
    },
    {
        "comment": "hou",
        "addedon": "2019-03-01 12:16:12",
        "user_id": "18",
        "id": "44",
        "name": "Test User 3",
        "photo": "avatar10.png"
    },
    {
        "comment": "hi",
        "addedon": "2019-03-01 12:16:28",
        "user_id": "18",
        "id": "45",
        "name": "Test User 3",
        "photo": "avatar10.png"
    },
    {
        "comment": "hi",
        "addedon": "2019-03-01 12:16:45",
        "user_id": "18",
        "id": "46",
        "name": "Test User 3",
        "photo": "avatar10.png"
    },
    {
        "comment": "hi",
        "addedon": "2019-03-01 12:16:52",
        "user_id": "18",
        "id": "47",
        "name": "Test User 3",
        "photo": "avatar10.png"
    },
    {
        "comment": "gg",
        "addedon": "2019-03-01 12:17:09",
        "user_id": "18",
        "id": "48",
        "name": "Test User 3",
        "photo": "avatar10.png"
    },
    {
        "comment": "heyy",
        "addedon": "2019-03-01 12:31:26",
        "user_id": "1",
        "id": "49",
        "name": "chitransh",
        "photo": "user.png"
    },
    {
        "comment": "fff",
        "addedon": "2019-03-01 12:36:52",
        "user_id": "1",
        "id": "52",
        "name": "chitransh",
        "photo": "user.png"
    },
    {
        "comment": "hhh",
        "addedon": "2019-03-02 00:13:41",
        "user_id": "18",
        "id": "54",
        "name": "Test User 3",
        "photo": "avatar10.png"
    },
    {
        "comment": "jii",
        "addedon": "2019-03-02 02:33:55",
        "user_id": "1",
        "id": "61",
        "name": "chitransh",
        "photo": "user.png"
    },
    {
        "comment": "dsdsdsdsd",
        "addedon": "2019-03-03 03:44:33",
        "user_id": "1",
        "id": "63",
        "name": "chitransh",
        "photo": "user.png"
    }
],
"reply": {
    "22": [
        {
            "comment": "hahaha",
            "addedon": "2019-03-02 00:34:50",
            "user_id": "18",
            "id": "58",
            "name": "Test User 3",
            "photo": "avatar10.png"
        },
        {
            "comment": "@chitransh heyyy",
            "addedon": "2019-03-03 03:44:59",
            "user_id": "1",
            "id": "65",
            "name": "chitransh",
            "photo": "user.png"
        },
        {
            "comment": "@chitransh heyy test user",
            "addedon": "2019-03-03 03:45:23",
            "user_id": "1",
            "id": "66",
            "name": "chitransh",
            "photo": "user.png"
        },
        {
            "comment": "@chitransh hiw are you",
            "addedon": "2019-03-03 04:06:09",
            "user_id": "1",
            "id": "67",
            "name": "chitransh",
            "photo": "user.png"
        }
    ],
    "23": [
        {
            "comment": "@chitransh hhhh",
            "addedon": "2019-03-02 01:04:58",
            "user_id": "18",
            "id": "59",
            "name": "Test User 3",
            "photo": "avatar10.png"
        }
    ],
    "24": [],
    "25": [],
    "26": [],
    "27": [],
    "28": [],
    "29": [],
    "30": [],
    "31": [
        {
            "comment": "@chitranshdsdsdsdsd",
            "addedon": "2019-03-02 05:07:44",
            "user_id": "1",
            "id": "62",
            "name": "chitransh",
            "photo": "user.png"
        }
    ],
    "32": [],
    "33": [],
    "37": [],
    "42": [],
    "43": [],
    "44": [],
    "45": [],
    "46": [],
    "47": [],
    "48": [],
    "49": [
        {
            "comment": "chitransh hi",
            "addedon": "2019-03-01 12:32:47",
            "user_id": "1",
            "id": "50",
            "name": "chitransh",
            "photo": "user.png"
        },
        {
            "comment": "chitransh sdff",
            "addedon": "2019-03-01 12:33:00",
            "user_id": "1",
            "id": "51",
            "name": "chitransh",
            "photo": "user.png"
        },
        {
            "comment": "chitransh hi",
            "addedon": "2019-03-01 12:42:59",
            "user_id": "1",
            "id": "53",
            "name": "chitransh",
            "photo": "user.png"
        }
    ],
    "52": [],
    "54": [
        {
            "comment": "@Test User 3kjj",
            "addedon": "2019-03-02 01:20:55",
            "user_id": "18",
            "id": "60",
            "name": "Test User 3",
            "photo": "avatar10.png"
        }
    ],
    "61": [
        {
            "comment": "@chitranshdsdsdsdsdsd",
            "addedon": "2019-03-03 03:44:40",
            "user_id": "1",
            "id": "64",
            "name": "chitransh",
            "photo": "user.png"
        }
    ],
    "63": []
}
```

}

Done with data JSONArray , now working for replies
as you can see in reply JSONArray I will get id from data so I am storing that id in my Map as key ex.

```
 Map<String,Arraylist<ReplyCommentModel>>
```

so String refers to that id .

now on buttonOnClick in RecyclerView item 
I am using this code -- >

```
 viewRepliesButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        if (collpased){
            collpased = false;
            replyRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            GroupAdapter<ViewHolder> adapter = new GroupAdapter<>();
            replyRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            replyRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
            replyCommentModels = replyModelsMap.get(String.valueOf(model.comment_id));
            if(replyCommentModels != null){
                Log.e("replComments ","Size" +replyCommentModels.size());
                for(ReplyCommentModel replyCommentModel : replyCommentModels){
                    adapter.add(new ReplyCommentItem(replyCommentModel,context));
                }
            }
            viewRepliesButton.setText("hide");
        } else {
            collpased = true;
            replyRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            viewRepliesButton.setText("Tap to view reply");

        }
    });
```

but all of the items in map are visible In recyclerView is there some problem in my code? 
Since I am passing value of comment id from my adapter item model is the Data key from JSON response  you can see above 
now I am clicking on the list and passing its id to map to get the array list of that particular id , maybe map is used to do this or there is some other preferable way to do this ?
new in using Map<> with Arraylist tbh , any proper guidance will be appreciated

and I am saving my map as like this

```
private Map<String,ArrayList<ReplyCommentModel>> replyModelMap = new HashMap<>();
 try {
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);

            String status = obj.getString("result");
            if (status.equals("success")) {
                JSONArray jsonArray = obj.getJSONArray("data");
                if(model.size() == 0){
                    fetchComments(jsonArray);
                   JSONObject replyObject = obj.getJSONObject("reply");
                   for(int i=0;i<model.size();i++){
                       JSONArray replyArrays = replyObject.getJSONArray(String.valueOf(model.get(i).comment_id));
                       for(int j=0;j<replyArrays.length();j++){
                           JSONObject jsonObject1 = replyArrays.getJSONObject(j);
                           Integer id = jsonObject1.getInt("id");
                           String name = jsonObject1.getString("name");
                           String comment_image = jsonObject1.getString("photo");
                           Integer user_id = jsonObject1.getInt("user_id");
                           String comment = jsonObject1.getString("comment");
                           String added_on = jsonObject1.getString("addedon");
                           String imageURl = Constant.IMAGE_URL+Constant.COMMENT_USER_IMAGE_URL+comment_image;
                           replyModel.add(new ReplyCommentModel(comment,name,imageURl,added_on,user_id,id));
                       }
                       if(replyModel != null){
                           replyModelMap.put(String.valueOf(model.get(i).comment_id),replyModel);

                       }
                   }
                    Log.e("ReplyModelMapSize","----> "+replyModelMap.size());
                    setUpRecyclerview();
                }else{
                    model.clear();
                    fetchComments(jsonArray);
                    upDateRecyclerView();
                }
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try initialising replyModel list inside the inner for loop, it seems all the items getting added to the same  list and the same being added to the with all the keys.Hence resulting the entire list with all the keys.Like this:-

```
                  for(int i=0;i<model.size();i++){
                   JSONArray replyArrays = replyObject.getJSONArray(String.valueOf(model.get(i).comment_id));
                  //Initialise inside the loop 
                  ArrayList<ReplyCommentModel> replyModel = new ArrayList();
                   for(int j=0;j<replyArrays.length();j++){
                       JSONObject jsonObject1 = replyArrays.getJSONObject(j);
                       Integer id = jsonObject1.getInt("id");
                       String name = jsonObject1.getString("name");
                       String comment_image = jsonObject1.getString("photo");
                       Integer user_id = jsonObject1.getInt("user_id");
                       String comment = jsonObject1.getString("comment");
                       String added_on = jsonObject1.getString("addedon");
                       String imageURl = Constant.IMAGE_URL+Constant.COMMENT_USER_IMAGE_URL+comment_image;
                       replyModel.add(new ReplyCommentModel(comment,name,imageURl,added_on,user_id,id));
                   }
                   if(replyModel != null){
                       replyModelMap.put(String.valueOf(model.get(i).comment_id),replyModel);

                   }
               }
```